# IC boost converter performs poorly in breadboard prototype circuit: is this to be expected?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, breadboard, boost

I'm using a TLV61220 IC boost converter to get 3.3V from a 1.5V AAA battery. I've built the circuit as specified on the datasheet (p. 1 of http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv61220.pdf) with R1 at 1MΩ and the appropriate value for R2. The converter outputs 3.3V as expected with a small load, but appears not to be able to handle loads that draw more than a couple of mA (the output drops to about 1.8V with a 1K load, for example). The battery should of course be capable of supplying much more current than this, and figure 3 on p. 7 of the datasheet suggests that the converter should be too.

I was wondering if this sort of performance is to be expected given that the prototype circuit is on a solderless breadboard (and that the TLV61220 is hooked up via one of the crappy SOT-23 to DIP converters sold by Digikey). I've read that high frequency circuits do not perform well on breadboards, but I'm unsure whether it's plausible to put the extremely poor performance down to this factor alone. On the other hand, if the circuit was not hooked up correctly, then it seems unlikely that I'd be getting 3.3V output with small loads.

(I've tried with two different TL61220s with exactly the same results.)

Comment: Update: It seems that the breadboard is a least a factor. I tried replacing some unnecessarily long wires with shorter ones and got it up to 2V from 1.8V for a 1K load.

Comment: What kind of inductor are you using?

Comment: One of these: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TSL0808RA-4R7M3R5-PF/445-3742-1-ND/1913606

Comment: Another problem: many SMPS chips require solid traces to copper fills for heat dissipation, using the PCB ground plane as a heatsink. These tiny chips simply cannot withstand the heat by its own. On a prototype board, it's difficult to get the heat dissipated via the flying leads, it can trigger thermal protection and the chip simply shuts down - a common issue that stops them from working on a prototype board. These SOT-23 to DIP converters could create this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solderless breadboards are useless for prototyping circuits over a few hundred kHz. For high frequencies, you need to construct your prototype circuits "deadbug" style over a copper clad ground plane, like so:

[image: deadbug construction]

Comment: Thanks. Just in case this info is useful to anyone else, I can confirm that the solderless breadboard was the issue. I tried constructing the circuit on a soldered breadboard (but not using a ground plane as in the picture) and the output went up to 2.5V with a 1K load. So the layout and construction of the circuit does indeed make a huge difference in this case.

Comment: @Bitrex OK - I'll bite - what's "Oliver"?

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't expect a 1MHz boost converter to work well on a breadboard.  The SOT to DIP adapter would add parasitic inductance.  The breadboard itself would add parasitic capacitance.

In general, switch mode power supplies can be layout sensitive.  If I were doing a PCB layout, I would just replicate the layout of the [evaluation kit for TLV61220](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvu671/slvu671.pdf) (pp.6-7).